# Consultas diferentes mas retornar os valores na mesma tabela

Tags: php

Tenho duas consultas diferentes, logo tenho duas variáveis com o resultado de cada uma das consultas, mas queria mostrar tudo na mesma tabela, como o faço em pHP?

```
$sql = "SELECT Product , SUM(Amount) AS 'Total 2017' FROM dbcentro.Registo WHERE YEAR(RegistrationDate) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY Product;";
$sql1 = "SELECT Produto, CAST(Total/3 AS DECIMAL(15,1)) AS 'Média 1º Trimestre' FROM(SELECT Product AS Produto, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM dbcentro.Registo WHERE MONTH(RegistrationDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND YEAR(RegistrationDate) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY Product) Soma;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
```

O que pretendia era que a coluna Média 1 trimestre aparecesse aqui o resultado na tabela como mostra a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas primeria colunas são da primeira consulta e agora quero que o resultado da segunda consulta apareça naquela coluna, mas ainda não consegui isso.

Resolvi o problema criando um while dentro de outro while

Comment: Coloque na resposta um pedaço de código de como está fazendo. Mesmo com erros. Para que possamos te ajudar

Comment: Se ambas as consultas retornarem a mesma quantidade de colunas creio que o union resolveria, ou ate mesmo a mesma query poderia buscar tudo, porem poste o codigo que tem para cada consulta hoje para ficar mais facil ajudarmos.

Comment: coloca as duas consultas que tem o mesmo resultado

Comment: não sei está errado no seu código ou só aqui mas você colocou `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` duas vezes (acredito que uma das duas deveria ser com a `$sql1`)

Comment: Não tenho erros no código e eu não quero juntar as duas consultas, o que pretendo é depois mostrar as colunas que quero de uma consulta e da outra na mesma tabela

Comment: O que pretendia, era perceber no while como mostro a coluna produto e total 2017 da primeira consulta e a coluna Média 1º Trimestre da segunda consulta dentro da mesma tabela que crio

Comment: sugeria que complementasses a tua pergunta com esses comentários, e tentasses esclarecer mais um pouco para tentarmos ajudar.

Comment: Se resolveu poste a solução no local indicado para tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base no SQL que o Walmir te passou funciona! e também da para fazer utilizando "IF":

```
SELECT 
    Product,
    SUM(Amount) AS 'Total 2017',
    CAST(SUM(if(MONTH(RegistrationDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 , Amount, 0)) / 3  AS DECIMAL (15 , 1 )) AS 'Média 1º Trimestre'
FROM
    dbcentro.Registo
WHERE
    YEAR(RegistrationDate) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY Product;
```

Comment: Everaldo costa, eu preciso de fazer a média para todos os trimestres deste ano, mas por exemplo no trimestre em que nos encontramos, queria dividir só pelos meses que temos deste semestre e não logo por três, mas queria colocar isso automático, consegues ajudar me?

Comment: No where colocar para ignorar o mes corrente, exemplo: 
WHERE    YEAR(RegistrationDate) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(RegistrationDate) != MONTH(curdate())

Comment: E para calcular conforme a quantidade mês dentro do trimestre:
SELECT 
    Product,
    SUM(Amount) AS 'Total 2017',
    CAST(SUM(if(MONTH(RegistrationDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 , Amount, 0)) / count(distinct MONTH(RegistrationDate))  AS DECIMAL (15 , 1 )) AS 'Média 1º Trimestre',

Comment: Este exemplo não está a funcionar, porque não está a dividir só pelos três meses, penso que está a dividir pelos meses de 2017 todos, que são 7 meses

Comment: Verifica se colocar isto para contar a quantidade de meses da certo: count(distinct if(MONTH(RegistrationDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 , MONTH(RegistrationDate), null))

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar o calculo de média do 1º Trimestre em apenas um select:

```
SELECT 
    Product , 
    SUM(Amount) AS 'Total 2017',
    CAST(SUM(case when MONTH(RegistrationDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3  then Amount else 0 end)/3 as DECIMAL(15,1)) as 'Média 1º Trimestre'
    FROM dbcentro.Registo 
    WHERE YEAR(RegistrationDate) = YEAR(NOW()) 
        GROUP BY Product;
```

Comment: eu não quero a união das duas consultas, o que pretendo é mostrar depois as colunas que quero de cada consulta na mesma tabela na parte visual do php

Comment: Você precisa chamar a variável $result e $result1 através de outra função, https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php . Normalize o nome das AS da sua consulta sem espaços e caracteres especiais. Troque os espaços pelo underline.

Comment: Editei minha resposta anterior. Veja por favor se resolve o seu problema...

Comment: Sim, esta solução é melhor do que aquela que eu cheguei que foi colocar um while dentro de outro, mas agora eu precisava de calcular os trimestres todos do ano 2017 mas que dividisse de uma forma automática, porque por exemplo agora neste trimestre que estamos ainda não posso dividir por 3 meses e sim por dois, mas se for manual não é a forma correta. Não sei se me fiz entender

Comment: Testa essa função TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, RegistrationDate, NOW())

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo, por favor?